# cannot insert DBNULL value into sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, dbnull

Why i get this error?

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

when i inserted null value for a numeric datatype in sql server 2005

Here is my code,

```
 if (MeasurementTr.Visible == true)
    {
        materialIn.measurementId = Convert.ToInt64(DlMeasurement.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        materialIn.measurementId = Convert.ToInt64(DBNull.Value);
    }
```

**EDIT** :

Is this right??

```
 materialIn.measurementId = (Convert.ToInt64(DlMeasurement.SelectedValue.ToString()) != 0) ? Convert.ToInt64(DlMeasurement.SelectedValue.ToString()) : 0;
```

Comment: No. you cannot convert DBNull to Int64. You need to validate first that the object value isn't DBNull!

Comment: It's the `else` block that's the problem.  I'm sure that the `if` block is fine (`ToString` can never return `DBNull.Value`).  As I said - use the `SetNull` or `SetmeasurementIdNull` method on the `DataRow`, if that's what it is, or just set it to `null` or `default(Int64)` if it's non-nullable.

Comment: @Aaronaught I missed the else part... you right and +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot convert `DBNull.Value` to `Int64` as your code attempts to do in `Convert.ToInt64`.  `DBNull.Value` means "unknown" or "nonexistent" and therefore there is no logical conversion to any other data type.

If the `materialIn` instance is some form of strongly-typed `DataRow`, it will have a `SetMeasurementIdNull` method, which is what you need to use.  If you're using Linq to SQL or EF, you shouldn't need to deal with `DBNull` at all, you would instead just write `materialIn.measurementId = null`.

Answer (score 1):

Because that `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.`

So what you need to do is to check the value for `DBNull`.

> materialIn.measurementId =  DlMeasurement.SelectedValue == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(DlMeasurement.SelectedValue.ToString());

Comment: @Mendy Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: But SelectedValue is object, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

DBNull doesn't convert to an Int64.  You will need to use a nullable int and then store null in the value or do something with the value to represent null such as 0 that can be stored in your property.